# Invertibility of a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

In Serge Lang's Linear Algebra textbook 3rd edition, there is an exercise in chapter 3.4, exercise 8 (a) which asks us to demonstrate that the linear map defined below is invertible.

Let $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear map as defined by $L(x, y, z) = (x - y, x + z, x + y +2z)$.

I'm wondering if there is an error. For example, $L(1, 1, -1)=(0, 0, 0)$, so the kernel is nonzero. Hence $L$ is not injective and therefore is not invertible.

Comment: Your logic is sound.  If the problem is as stated (and it's not asking whether the map is invertible), then it is incorrect.

Comment: @Aaron, Thanks. I couldn't find any errata posted for the textbook. The question states "Show that L is invertible in each case". There are two parts (a) and (b). (a) must have a typo unless my eyes are tricking me.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron; note $x+y+2z=2(x+z)-(x-y)$